# What aren't my X, Y, Z axis going in the right direction?

Tags: axis

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to move this sphere up or down (z) axis, but the z axis seems to be acting like the X and Y axis -  as in, going from side to side rather than up or down. Is there a way to reset the axes?

Comment: you must have changed the Transform Orientations, take a look in the Transform Orientations panel

Comment: You're right, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have changed the *Transform Orientations*, take a look into the *Transform Orientations* panel and choose the one you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) That's fixed it!